# AVR Studio build error 255

Tags: avr, avr-studio5

I am running through a tutorial for making a LUFA, VirtualSerial project with AVR studio 5. When I clean the project no errors are shown but when I build I get the following error message:

```
    -f was unexpected at this time.
    make: *** [sizebefore] Error 255
```

Has anyone else had this message and knows what to do?

Thanks

Comment: make is executing shell commands from a script. If the syntax doesn't match the system the command won't work, e.g., windows shell vs bash shell, etc. `-f` is usually a command option in bash. Maybe the option is not available in your shell. Maybe the command needs quotes around it. It is hard to tell without more information.

Comment: @UncleO Thanks for the comment, I found a solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a answer I have found a solution! installation of winAVR toolchain. I read somewhere that LUFA needs the winAVR toolchain, which is not included in Atmel studio 5. I cannot find the link, but it solved the issue.